# How to remove a _UIAlertNormalizingOverlayWindow 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

In my application I need to remove any alerts visible in the window, when the app goes to background.But the problem is that, I don't want to dismiss it with

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]
```

because, it will trigger the `clickedButtonAtIndex` Delegate and will invoke a method.I wan't to avoid this when app goes to background.

I did it successfully by removing the **alertView** from the **subViews** of **window** using the following code

```
  for (UIWindow *window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        for (UIView *view in [window subviews]) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }

        }
```

But the problem is that the **_UIAlertNormalizingOverlayWindow** is still there and it blocks the user Interaction.I need to remove the **_UIAlertNormalizingOverlayWindow** also from my window.
Please help me to do this or please suggest any alternatives to achieve the solution .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's not a very clean solution (assumes ivar `BOOL _backgroundAlertFlag`

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    _backgroundAlertFlag = YES;

    // find your UIAlertView as you are doing already

    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
    _backgroundAlertFlag = NO;
}
```

Then in your `UIAlertViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if( !_backgroundAlertFlag )
    {
        // handle alert processing normally here
    }
    // other wise ignore (just dismiss)
}
```

Comment: Thanks alan.But I am looking for a general solution for the problem.

Comment: I'd say this is a general solution, as the overlay window is private API that you can't touch if you want to ship on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've been able to tell, there is no way to remove UIWindows. The only thing you can do is make a different window key and visible.